# Styling search <input> with css

Tags: css

I am trying to style a search input box, such that, when the user, click into the box, it changes to a different color, and to get rid of the blue outline that indicates that the user has selected the text box.

Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7t5AY/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text-search" placeholder="Search" >
```

Comment: Side note: http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:focus` selector, e.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7t5AY/1/)

```
input[type=text]:focus{
    outline:none; /* removes the blue outline on focus */
    background:lightgrey; /* however you wish to style */
    border:1px solid black; /* however you wish to style */
}
```

[**Or more stylishly..**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7t5AY/2/)

Note that in HTML5, `input type="search"` [is a  valid designation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)